# What is the difference between != and =! in Java?

Tags: java, syntax

I was looking over some mock [OCJP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Certification_Program) questions. I came across a really baffling syntax. Here it is:

```
class OddStuff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean b = false;
        System.out.println((b != b));// False
        System.out.println((b =! b));// True
    }
}
```

Why does the output change between `!=` and `=!`?

Comment: Note that if you assign `true` to b, then both return false.

Comment: Not enough whitespace is just as bad as too much whitespace

Comment: Same programmer writing Java and C++ . Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029174/whats-this-operator :P

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The question is just playing with you with confusing spacing.

`b != b` is the usual `!=` (not equals) comparison.

On the other hand:

`b =! b` is better written as `b = !b` which is parsed as:

```
b = (!b)
```

Thus it's two operators.

1. First invert `b`.
2. Then assign it back to `b`.

The assignment operator returns the assigned value. Therefore, `(b =! b)` evaluates to true - which is what you print out.

Comment: correct and more correctly it's (b = !b) vs. (b != b)

Comment: I didn't know assignments could be done in that manner.

Comment: @Prometheus87 Yes, you can put assignments inside statements.

Comment: Also key is the fact that assignments evaluate to the assigned value, so `System.out.println(b = !b)` is printing the value of `b` after `!b` is assigned to it.

Comment: @PaulBellora Yes, adding that to my answer.

Comment: What if it's `!(!b)`

Answer (score 11):

`b != b` means `! (b == b)`: the opposite of `b == b`.

`b =! b` is actually `b = !b`, an assignment. It's toggling `b`'s value. An assignment evaluates to the value of the expression, so this will evaluate to `!b` (along with having changed the value of `b`).

Answer (score 9):

`b=!b` is an assignment. It assigns `b` to `!b` and the expression evaluates to the resulting value, which is `true`.

Answer (score 3):

b =! b

you are doing an assignment, you are saying that B should have the value of !B.

b != b

You are asking if B is different than b